# regEx with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I would to get sting with parsing txt file, my string is:

```
[INFO] Total time: 12 minutes 10 seconds
```

I need is only "12 minutes 10 seconds"

my expression is:

```
/Total time: [0-9]* minute[a-z]* [0-9]* second[a-z]*/
```

it works perfectly, but if sting is only 1 minute it does not work...

how to get all sting after "Total time:" ?

Comment: that's not a very useful comment, @Esailija

Comment: @KaeVerens, I swear I saw exactly the same question, regex, and string to match just a few days ago :D Cannot find it though, but it doesn't get more duplicate than that :P

Comment: @Roman - if you need the part starting with "12" (in your example), why is your regex including "Total time: "? Do you want the words "Total time: " in your output or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/Total time: ([0-9]* minutes?)?( ?[0-9]* seconds?)*/
```

You need a `?` to match 0 or 1 preceding.

Comment: I like your solution more then my own: Total time: [0-9]* minute[a-z]* [0-9]* second[a-z]*|[0-9]* minute[a-z]*

Comment: great! but.. what about if string contain only seconds? for ex. Total time: 22 sedonds?

Comment: There's a `space` matching was missing. See the updated expression

Answer (score 2):

You could turn that seconds part into a subgroup and make it optional via the '?'

```
/Total time: [0-9]* minutes?( [0-9]* seconds?)?/
```

Comment: +1 for being the first person to fix the optional "s" in "minutes" and "seconds".

Answer (score 1):

let's say the line is `line`

```
line=line.replace(/^\[INFO\] Total time: /, '');
```